# How to add a particular CSS for particular app

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have a live website which I want to show in my app with WebView. But also I want to add a css file in my website which will only work if This particular app load the website. Otherwise that css will not work.
Is this possible? If possible please anyone can tell me how to do that?

Comment: from which side you want to do that - from the app's side, or from the website's side?

Comment: By any side. I just want to do it Somehow.

Comment: you can do from both - **from the web site**: set custom user-agent for your WebVIew, detect User-agent on the web site, include specific CSS in the HTML. **From the app side**: add listener on page load finished to the WebView, in which add the CSS to the page source.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Can you please give me an example or hint to ho how to do that?

Comment: what exactly of all I have written?

Comment: Oh Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `index.html` of your Website and the `css file` in the `assets` folder of your Android project. Modify your `index.html` so it will load the `css file` by adding a link to it.

Then when loading the WebView, just load the `index.html` from your `assets` folder and you are done. Like so: `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")`